# encodeForHTMLAttribute or encodeForJavascript -XSS

Tags: jsp, xss, scriptlet

I have the following code snippet and I am encoding it to prevent from XSS .

```
<% if (answerList.size() > 2){
 out.write("<td width='30%' class='label'        nowrap='nowrap'><label> "+ address value +"</label></td>");

  }%>
```

Here I have to encode the address value . if Anything comes inside scriptlet tag is JAVA CODE then I should consider using encodeForJavascript() or since it's just rendering html I should consider using encodeForHTMLAttribute(). It may sound silly the way I put but really I need someone to guide . I couldn't find enough resource for proper understanding on this . Thanks in advance

Update: now I have seen something new and I would like to update my question further.

```
<td>
<%
 out.Write(request.getParameter("address");
 %>
</td>
```

In the above code it's a scriptlet again but the html tags are placed outside . Which one should I consider

Answer (score 0):

`encodeForJavascript` is only suitable for some JavaScript code, but not Java.

You should encode based on the rendered output, which is HTML.`encodeForHTMLAttribute` will do for attributes. Here you have a value between tags instead of an attribute, so you can use `encodeForHTML`.

If you then try rendering a value with quotes for example, then you should see the output with entity encoding, and rendered correctly in the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the response . Can you please provide some links where I can get detailed explanation on this.

Comment: @ani See: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet